# Assets files not read in the uploaded Laravel project

Tags: laravel, heroku, heroku-postgres

Everything has been connected, but the problem is in the page formatting and the style is not loaded or read, why, what is the problem, is it in La Ravel or is it missing a definition that I did not do, I wish for help
The site link for those who like to see it
https://chance-3-620ac52b9ddc.herokuapp.com/

I expect that he is reading all the files as long as their path is correct at the time of design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options

- Force Https using Laravel

Add to (`AppServiceProvider::boot()`)

```php
if($this->app->isProduction()) {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

- Update nginx default config (I don't think so you can do in Heroku)

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

- Update .env (easy one):

```
APP_URL=https://chance-3-620ac52b9ddc.herokuapp.com
ASSET_URL=https://chance-3-620ac52b9ddc.herokuapp.com
```

Comment: The method did not work but thank you

Comment: Which method ? Did you try to clear the config (`php artisan config:clear`) or since you in dev mode you can execute (`php artisan optimize:clear`)

Comment: yes i  clear the config  and optimize the project 
But it is not a problem with the code but a problem I don't know where it doesn't read all assets files I think you've seen the shape that appears. I uploaded the project previously on 000webhost it worked fine but I converted only because of security etc But the problem is in Heroku itself there may be a problem in reading the files

Comment: I think you don't understand.. you are loading http over https (the last option it should work for you) ..  how do you load your assets ?can you show us ? 'your URL should be https:// not http:// .. check in the devtools.)

Comment: You're a genius. It worked from here. 
ASSET_URL=https://chance-3-620ac52b9ddc.herokuapp.com

Thank you very much. 
Is there a video to explain more about this matter more